# Function of two Random Variables using Inverse Transformation

Tags: probability

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be jointly continuous random variables with joint pdf $f_{X_1, X_2}$.  Let's say I want to compute $E(g\circ(X_1,X_2))$ for some measurable function $g$.  Written out, this is
$$
E(g\circ(X_1,X_2) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} g(x_1,x_2)f_{X_1, X_2}(x_1,x_2)\, dx_1dx_2,
$$

Now let $U_1,U_2 \sim Unif[0,1]$ be independent and let $F_{X_1, X_2}$ be the joint cdf of $(X_1,X_2)$.  **I'd like to use the inverse transformation method to write the expectation above in terms of $U_1$ and $U_2$,** but I'm not sure how to generate samples from a joint distribution.  I know if we define $X_1 := F^{-1}_{X_1}(U_1)$ and $X_2 := F^{-1}_{X_2}(U_2)$ then $X_1 \sim F_{X_1}$ and $X_2 \sim F_{X_2}$, but how would I get samples $(X_1,X_2) \sim F_{X_1,X_2}$?  Then, how could the expectation above be written?

Comment: Since the cdf is the integral of the pdf, my first thought would be to use integration by parts or something similar.